# Cross browser File input validation in asp.net 2.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, file-upload

input type file or the file upload html control/ asp.net control value seems to change depending on browsers.

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
```

Chrome:
fileUpload.value gives c:\fakePath\filename

Firefox:
fileUpload.value gives filename.ext

ie:
fileUpload.value gives Full path+filename

i used a regular expression validator with validation expression as below

```
^[a-za-zA-Z0-9_\.]{3,28}\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$
```

**carries out below process:**

1. File name must be 3 to 28 characters

2.Extension must match the group only.

Since the value of fileUpload control is different in different browsers how do i validate it now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fraz Sundal couldn't comment with the code hence the new post
@Fraz still no clue why it fails here is the code snippet`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="rgvFile" runat="server" font-bold="true" errormessage="Only pdf,doc,zip,jpeg,png,gif files allowed"
                                        cssclass="rgvfile" enableclientscript="true" display="Dynamic" controltovalidate="fileUpload"
                                        validationexpression="^[a-za-zA-Z0-9_\.]{3,28}\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$"
                                        text="Only pdf, doc, zip, jpeg, png, gif files allowed" tooltip="Only certain files allowed and filename cannot contain space.Please check and retry"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>`

in client side the validation expression turns to `^[a-za-zA-Z0-9_\.]{3,28}\\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$` might be because of that

Answer (score 0):

If you only use standard RegularExpressionValidator then it will work cross browser itself. Because RegularExpressionValidator works client side too when you select a file it automatically display the ErrorMessage if the file is invalid.

**Sample Code**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fup" runat="server" />        
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="fup" ErrorMessage="Invalid File" 
ValidationExpression="^[a-za-zA-Z0-9_\.]{3,28}\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Is it so!!. Could you put up a simple form to test above regular expression in question and view in Chrome, Safari, firefox. Primary reason question was raised because it didn't work

Comment: This code is working on IE, Firefox and Chrome. I think its more than enough to check cross browser on three main browsers

Comment: i will get back after some more testing

Comment: Please try the below it doesn't work         `<asp:FileUpload id="fup" runat="server" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" controltovalidate="fup" enableclientscript="true"
            errormessage="Invalid File" text="invalid file" validationexpression="^[a-za-zA-Z0-9_\.]{3,28}\.(pdf|txt|doc|docx|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|zip|rar)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` event though i input valid file `sprite.png` it says invalid file